# Construct date time string from current date time using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to construct a date time string using AMPscript in the format `yyyy-mmm-ddThh:mm:ss` based on the current time (where `T` is a letter). Is it possible to achieve this without using the `Concat()` function? Here's what I have at the moment:

```
Concat(FormatDate(now(), "", "yyyy-MM-ddT"),FormatDate(now(), "", "hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use the [format()](https://ampscript.guide/format/) function instead of [formatDate()](https://ampscript.guide/formatdate)?

```
%%=format(now(),"yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss")=%%
```

**Output**

`2016-09-29T08:18:51`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `hh:mm:ss` timeformat in [FormatDate](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/date-time/FormatDate.html) it self.

```
%%=FormatDate(now(),"yyyy-MM-ddT","hh:mm:ss")=%%
```

**Output:** 2016-09-28T04:02:36

Comment: This does not work for me as I get the output: `2016-09-28T 11:34:21`. Note that a space character is inserted after `T`. Are you sure that you are seeing this exact output? This works for me `%%=Replace(FormatDate(now(),"yyyy-MM-ddT","hh:mm:ss"),' ','')=%%` but is `Replace()` really required?

Comment: Yeah, im also get the output  `2016-09-29T 11:46:21` in landing page and now, `Replace` function is required to remove the space character. i'm not sure why space character is not coming in ContentBlock.